# How do I remove thumbnail slider arrow implemented from CDN

Tags: javascript

I have implemented thumbnail slider following example from the link https://splidejs.com/thumbnail-slider/. The result has reflected fine as I expected now I want to remove the arrows and the progress bar, where both arrow and progress bar added from CDN. how to achieve this.

OUTPUT PICTURE

[image: RESULT PICTURE]

HEADER FILES

```js
 <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@splidejs/splide@latest/dist/js/splide.min.js"></script>
```

```
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@splidejs/splide@latest/dist/css/splide.min.css">

 <script type="text/javascript" src="catalog.js"></script>
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="catalog.css">
```

HTML CODE

Primary slider

```
div id="primary-slider" class="splide">
<div class="splide__track col-md-7">
<ul class="splide__list">
  <li class="splide__slide">
    <img src="pic3.jfif">
  </li>
  <li class="splide__slide">
    <img src="pic3.jfif">
  </li>
  <li class="splide__slide">
    <img src="pic1.jpg">
  </li>
   <li class="splide__slide">
    <img src="pic3.jfif">
  </li>
  <li class="splide__slide">
    <img src="pic3.jfif">
  </li>
  <li class="splide__slide">
    <img src="pic1.jpg">
  </li>
</ul>
```

Secondary slider

```
 <div id="secondary-slider" class="splide">
  <div class="splide__track col-md-7">
   <ul class="splide__list">
    <li class="splide__slide">
     <img src="pic3.jfif">
    </li>
    <li class="splide__slide">
     <img src="pic3.jfif">
   </li>
   <li class="splide__slide">
     <img src="pic1.jpg">
   </li>
   <li class="splide__slide">
     <img src="pic3.jfif">
   </li>
   <li class="splide__slide">
    <img src="pic3.jfif">
   </li>
   <li class="splide__slide">
     <img src="pic1.jpg">
   </li>
 </ul>
```

JS CODE

```
document.addEventListener( 'DOMContentLoaded', function () {
var secondarySlider = new Splide( '#secondary-slider', {
    fixedWidth  : 100,
    height      : 60,
    gap         : 10,
    cover       : true,
    isNavigation: true,
    focus       : 'center',
    breakpoints : {
        '600': {
            fixedWidth: 66,
            height    : 40,
        }
    },
} ).mount();



var primarySlider = new Splide( '#primary-slider', {
    type       : 'fade',
    heightRatio: 0.5,
    pagination : false,
    arrows     : false,
    cover      : true,
} ); // do not call mount() here.

primarySlider.sync( secondarySlider ).mount();
```

} );

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you need is to set `pagination` and `arrows` to `false` like this

```
var primarySlider = new Splide( '#primary-slider', {
    type       : 'fade',
    heightRatio: 0.5,
    pagination : false,
    arrows     : false,
    cover      : true,
    pagination : false, // disable pagination
    arrows     : false // disbale arrows
} );
```

> Repeat the same thing in `secondary_slider`

you could check all of the options [here](https://splidejs.com/options/)

Comment: Why  do not call mount() here?

Comment: @PHPFan it is just a typo from the original question thanks for mentioning that